# How can one test if a ruby is real?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, materials

My friend recently bought a ruby gem from a store and asked me how to test whether its an original one or a duplicate.

Are there any ways to test it using only domestic materials?

Comment: If the concern is that the ruby might be synthetic, then I'm fairly certain there are no chemical tests that can distinguish them, since synthetic rubies have the same basic elemental composition as natural ones, aside perhaps from trace impurities in natural ones. If that's the issue, only a professional will be able to reliably determine its authenticity. If you just want to identify it as a ruby and not some other type of stone, my suspicion is that testing it for hardness on the Mohs scale is the only unambiguous test you could do without professional expertise and equipment.

Comment: Ruby glows red under a UV lamp.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To test if it's ruby at home check it hardness. If it's harder than 7 even if it's not ruby it still something precious. :-) You can also try to find refraction index however for this you need some equipment. If you really want 100% prove, ask on a local chemistry faculty if they could "as a teaching example" make single crystal diffraction experiment. Simple run with 30 frames would be enough to find a cell what is enough to prove it's ruby.

Fitting your ruby on diffractometer would be challenge as a new diffractometers are working on crystals with size of 10--300 micrometers. To find if it natural or synthetic you need to go to specialize jeweler. They look for imperfections (natural stone are usually less perfect than synthetic).

Comment: Thanks for the answer,Well i have another query.is it possible to test for the hardness using domestic materials? I would be very much grateful to you if you please suggest me some ways to do the same.

Comment: @javaprogrammer: as you have another question, raise it as another proper question

Comment: @javaprogrammer Yes, it's [possible](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/412789/71860).